# system.IsScheduled() and Test Classes

Tags: scheduled-apex

This seems wrong to me, but maybe I am missing something simple...

I have this class:

```
global class GoogleAnalyticsImportScheduled implements Schedulable{
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    GoogleAnalyticsScheduledUpdates.executeScheduledUpdated(system.today().adddays(-1));
  }
}
```

Which is tested with this test method:

```
    test.StartTest();
    GoogleAnalyticsImportScheduled sh = new GoogleAnalyticsImportScheduled();
    String sch = '0 0 8 * * ?';
    system.schedule('GA DATA Import Test', sch, sh);
    test.StopTest();
```

That test method correctly calls GoogleAnalyticsScheduledUpdates, but the debug in that class says isScheduled() is false. Shouldn't it be TRUE, even in this test context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Testing the Apex Scheduler](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm#apex_scheduler_testing) docs: (my emphasis)

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes **are run synchronously**.

So it would appear they aren't truly being run in the standard async fashion, which may explain why [System.IsScheduled()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_System_isScheduled.htm) is returning false. It was invoked from the system collected calls rather than from an actual schedule.

That said, I agree that is is confusing. Maybe it is a bug?

I did find [System.isBatch() always false](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/System-isBatch-always-false/m-p/436949), which mentioned `System.isScheduled()` as well. That was back in 2012.

---

I don't know how it is implemented in practice, but I imagine Scheduled jobs run much like other Asynchronous jobs. There is a diagram in the [Asynchronous Processing in Force.com](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/async_processing/salesforce_async_processing.pdf) doc that shows jobs being passed out to various application servers for processing. In an automated test case it would be miles easier to keep it all on the same server and run them synchronous so the progress and outcome could be monitored.

[image]

Comment: Yes that was my developer board post. It had only just been released so I assumed it was just buggy. In the end I just created my own handler.

Comment: I think the part you placed in bold answers it - my guess is that in normal operations, they get placed in a queue with a tag to say how they got there (future, scheduled etc), but in tests, they are just added to the main synchronous flow, and that flag is false...but I'll ask some folks at DF to see if that is expected behavior..

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC I've added a bit more to the answer as I think it shows how the standard non-testing asynchronous queue puts jobs out to various servers. The testing synchronous queue probably creates a different flow which doesn't set the flag. If you can corner someone at DF for a more authoritative answer all the better :)